# get_option( 'home' ) not returning value in database

Tags: multisite

I am using multisite (subfolders) and have several subsites on it.  All have been working fine with no problems however one subsite is now not returning the correct value with get_option( 'home' ) for some reason - it was working fine for a while but just recently stopped working...

So now this subsite cannot create any new pages and link to the correct media etc and when I view the permalinks settings for this subsite none of the options include the assigned subsite path.

So to clarify my problem, I looked at the code in /wp/wp-admin/options-permalink.php and added the following code to line 125:

```
if ($_GET['debug'] === 'true'){
  echo 'current_blog_id: '. get_current_blog_id() .'<br />';
  echo 'blogname: '. get_option( 'blogname' ) .'<br />';
  echo 'siteurl: '. get_option( 'siteurl' ) .'<br />';
  echo 'home: '. get_option( 'home' ) .'<br />';
}
```

Everything outputs correctly except that get_option( 'home' ) is returning the wrong value for this subsite - it returns the the domain to my primary multisite. so for example it should return:
mymultisitenetwork.com/subsite9/
however it just returns:
mymultisitenetwork.com/

All the other values are returned correctly ( get_current_blog_id(), get_option( 'blogname' ), get_option( 'siteurl' )

When I check the other subsites in my network the get_option( 'home' ) returns the correct value for that subsite ( like: mymultisitenetwork.com/subsite2/ )

I checked the options table in the database for this subsite "wp_9_options" and it has the correct value in there "mymultisitenetwork.com/subsite9/"

So why when I output echo out get_option( 'home' ) it returns 
mymultisitenetwork.com/ instead of 
mymultisitenetwork.com/subsite9/ ??

I even tried clearing the cache before outputting get_option('home') with the following code but that didn't work either - still outputted the wrong data:

```
$GLOBALS['wp_object_cache']->delete( 'home', 'options' );
```

Please help to resolve this as this client can no logger create any new pages because of this..

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Note: because I cannot put links in this post I have removed http:// from the dummy links above.

Comment: Are you using `switch_to_blog()` anywhere? That's one possible culprit. Disable all plugins on the site in question, then see if the issue has gone away. If it has, turn your plugins back on one at a time until it recurs. That plugin is causing the issue. (If no plugin is the culprit, then switch to a default theme. If the issue goes away, then it's the fault of the theme.)

Comment: Also: *never hack core*. Editing files in the `wp-admin` directory will cause you grief the next time WordPress updates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have disabled all plugins and switched to the 2014 theme and its still not working.  No I am not using switch_to_blog() anywhere - at least to my knowledge.

Comment: Did you try `get_blog_option`?

Answer (score -2):

This may not be the answer in your case, but worth mentioning for anyone in similar situation. You can change "home" in the network admin's edit site page.

Direct link - if you know the blog id number add that to the end of: `yoursite.com/wp-admin/network/site-info.php?id=`

Or go to: `http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php` and find and edit the site from there.

Comment: When I view the edit screen for this subsite the settings look okay it has the right path value there.  Even if I change the "path" value to something else it still doesn't work.  For example, I changed the "path" value for this subsite to /newtest/ and then went and viewed the permalink settings for this subsite and it still doesn't include the "path" value in the suggested permalink options.  And when I echo out: get_option('home') it returns the domain for my main network.  All other subsites are working fine.

Comment: Also, I have disabled all plugins and switched to the 2014 theme and its still not working